# Add text into cell formula in Excel to automatically select an other column with a drop down

Tags: excel, drag-and-drop, formula, drag

This is quite an unsual question to fix my column problem from my Power Query mess.

I would like to add a text value to a selection name so it will dynamically select an other column name.

My goal is that my drop down would automatically do the following on every row from an other sheet:

```
=TableItems[@high]
=TableItems[@high.1]
=TableItems[@high.2]
```

[**What I want it to look like with dynamic drag formula**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsFqI.png)

Anyone know if it is possible to add a value to a cell selection without having any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to offset my column by using a new column which I have called "Formula" and I just hide it.

This is the procedure I have done:

I took my TableItems selection and I have created a OFFSET formula of

```
=OFFSET(ItemInfo!D2,1,**4**,1,1)
```

The number 4 in my table moves 4 times to the right each times, so I have created a formula to multiply the number 4 by 2,3,4,5,6 etc.

The formula is the following:

```
=OFFSET(ItemInfo!D2,1,$H3,1,1)
=OFFSET(ItemInfo!D2,1,$H4,1,1)  etc etc etc
```

[IMAGE OF THE RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGDeI.png)
I've had this problem for a couple of centuries, but I really hope this will help anyone else having a similar problem.